# Refreshing a UI to reflect items added to a list

Tags: c#, winforms, background

While my UI is displayed, data is being passed in the back end and added to a `List<string>` that I would in turn like to display on my UI.

I've seen several examples using background workers however I don't have access to the actual component due to how I layout my User Controls and programmatically build them.

Question: **How can I run this method repeatedly behind my UI without locking up my UI in a loop?**

```
public void UpdatePanel()
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        AddMethod(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try looking up for `BackgroundWorker` or `Task`

Comment: Something like `async Task.Run( () => { your stuff };` along `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)` to update some progress bar ?

Comment: *I've seen several examples using background workers however I don't have access to the actual component due to how I layout my User Controls and programmatically build them.* How come? You can create it in code simply.

Comment: What's the type of `list`?

Comment: Type List<string>

Comment: Instead of monitoring the list, you can use a `BindingList` or an `ObservableCollection` and receive event when the list changes.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop or time intervals to monitor a list, as an option when possible, you can use a [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and receive notification when list changes.

Then you can update user interface in the event handler which you attaced to `ListChanged` event of`BindingList<T>` or `CollectionChanged` event  of `ObservableCOllection<T>`.

**Example**

Here is an example based on `ObservableCollection<string>`.

```
ObservableCollection<string> list;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    list.CollectionChanged += list_CollectionChanged;
    list.Add("Item 1");
    list.Add("Item 2");
    list.RemoveAt(0);
    list[0] = "New Item";
}
void list_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        var items = string.Join(",", e.NewItems.Cast<String>());
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("'{0}' Added", items));
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        var items = string.Join(",", e.OldItems.Cast<String>());
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("'{0}' Removed", items));
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
    {
        var oldItems = string.Join(",", e.OldItems.Cast<String>());
        var newItems = string.Join(",", e.NewItems.Cast<String>());
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("'{0}' replaced by '{1}'", oldItems, newItems));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Reset or Move");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a far better solution to my problem than my initial area of thought. Thank you for the explanation and answer. @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task, Async and await, where is some code which insert an element in a listbox each second without blocking UI.

In your case, you have to return the data from backend asynchronously.

```
    public async void LoadItemsAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            listBox1.Items.Add(await GetItem());
    }

    public Task<string> GetItem()
    {
        return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return "Item";
        });
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm needing to do... my questions is to actually start this method do I just run it in my constructor for the form and it'll keep running automatically or is there something else to that?

Comment: Your backend call must return a task, that's the reason I use await, which get the result value from a Task, also in your code behind you have to decorate the method which calls your data with async.